# How to avoid page template duplication in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a generic page template in Nuxt which I want to use for multiple roots. I want the following urls to map to the same template (which then loads it's content from prismic api)

```
/:root-level-page
/products/:product
```

I can't see a way of doing this without the duplicating the page template in the pages folder like this

```
pages/_page.vue
pages/products/_page.vue
```

This would work fine by I can't bring myself to break the golden DRY rule.

Answer (score 1):

Think I've found the answer myself so will leave here. I now just have the page template in my pages folder

```
pages/_page.vue
```

I have then added the following to nuxt.config.js

```
router: {
extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
  routes.push({
    name: 'section-page',
    path: '/:section/:page',
    component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/_page.vue')
  })
}
```

}

This means the routes below all use the same page template

```
/about
/products/some-product
/some-other-section/some-other-page
```

Comment: Any other way of doing this? Like I'm in a same situation and want to handle this from the vue files only if possible

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Nuxt layouts](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#custom-layout).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/custom-layouts) is the official example from the Nuxt website.

You basically create a `.vue` SFC inside your `/layouts` directory and in your `pages/_page.vue` and `pages/products/_page.vue` files you just refer to it.

Comment: Thank for the reply, I've tried this out but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. I'm loading content from Prismic using async data in my page and that method isn't available in within a layout.